# Does Mathematica know if an integral is convergent or not?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider the following integrals that I asked *Mathematica* to do,

```
Assuming[m >= 1 && q >= 1 && k >= 1 && m ∈ Integers && k ∈ Integers, 
  Integrate[Exp[-2 π[m q Sqrt[λ + 1/4] + k Sqrt[λ]]], {λ, 0, ∞}]]

Integrate[Tanh[π Sqrt[λ]] Log[1 - Exp[-2 π q Sqrt[λ + 1/4]]], {λ, 0, ∞}]
```

for various different positive values of $m,k,q$ or in general

In each of these cases, *Mathematica* just rewrote back the integral doing nothing. Does this mean that the integral converges, but *Mathematica* doesn't know how to do it?

---

It would be an added bonus if someone can point out if and how these integrals can be done!

Comment: @Nasser Why do you think so? There is no error message. And this displays correctly on WolframAlpha - (the second integral with q=3) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_0^%E2%88%9E+tanh%28%CF%80+sqrt%28%CE%BB%29%29+log%281-exp%28-2+%CF%80+3+sqrt%28%CE%BB%2B1%2F4%29%29%29+d%CE%BB&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_*Math-

Comment: see ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HoevE.png)   You can't write `m[Element] Integers`, you can't write `Sqrt[[Lambda]]` etc...as I said, W/A accepts messy human input. But Mathematica needs exact syntax. May be in version 10, when the system becomes WL and unified, then your input will work. But now in version 9.01 it is giving errors.

Comment: I am doing here "copy as Input Text" - and Mathematica doesn't give any error messages on these - Integrate [  
 Tanh[ \[Pi] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]]*
  Log[ 1 - Exp[-2 \[Pi]  3 Sqrt [ \[Lambda] + 1/4 ] ]] , {\[Lambda], 
  0, Infinity }]

Comment: Can you see my reformatted pasting of the input? Its not really [pi] its actually "escape p i  escape" and so on and so forth

Comment: I copy pasted my text back into the file and there are no errors - I am on Mathematica 9 BTW

Comment: You still have error. You type Pi []  where you need to use Pi () for grouping. Do not use [] to group expression. see `Pi[ m*q` in your code... Pi is not a function. Your integrand is too hard for analytical solution. Removing the second Sqrt[lambda] helped. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h6hz5.png)

Comment: Can you give an example? I have uniformly used [] for all function arguments Log, Exp, Tanh ,Integrate, Sqrt, Assuming . (...somehow Mathematica is not giving any errors to me!...)

Comment: Yes, but Pi is not a function. You can't write Pi[....], well you can, but it makes no sense.

Comment: Okay..I changed that - still there is no answer - Mathematica just displays the stuff back - does it mean that its at least convergent?

Comment: I think yes, M would have said it does not converge if does not. But you can check. `Assuming[m >= 1 && q >= 1 && k >= 1 && m \[Element] Integers && 
  k \[Element] Integers, 
 Limit[Exp[-2*\[Pi] (m*q*Sqrt[\[Lambda] + 1/4] + 
      k*Sqrt[\[Lambda]])], \[Lambda] -> Infinity]]` gives zero. (you need to fix `Pi[]` error in your code. still there) since integrand goes to zero, there is a good chance the area below the function is zero. But this is for the math people to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer but it is too long for a comment.

I didn't look at your first integral, but the second is fairly easy to investigate because it only depends on one parameter. I used two *Mathematica* tools that often help in kind of situation you find yourself in.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Tanh[π Sqrt[λ]] Log[1 - Exp[-2 π q Sqrt[λ + 1/4]]], {λ, 0, 100}],
  {q, 0., 5., 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: manip.png]

Looking a the plot for various values of `q` suggest the integral converges and goes to zero as `q` gets large, which in turn suggests that [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NIntegrate.html) might be fruitful.

```
Table[NIntegrate[Tanh[π Sqrt[λ]] Log[1 - Exp[-2 π q Sqrt[λ + 1/4]]], {λ, 0, ∞}], {q, 1, 8}]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in λ near {λ} = {0.193495}. NIntegrate obtained -9.30632*10^-14 and 9.31004105035578`*^-19 for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> ```
> {-0.00710267, -0.000110031, -2.62324*10^-6, -7.42753*10^-8, 
>  -2.31044*10^-9, -7.62815*10^-11, -2.62445*10^-12, -9.30632*10^-14}
> ```

The results from `NIntegrate` also suggest the integral goes to zero as `q` goes to ∞, but that *Mathematica* runs out of computing steam at `q = 8` when confined to machine precision reals.

You should make yourself familiar with the use these tools (and others found in *Mathematica*) to investigate your integration problems.

Comment: Just because $f(x)$ decreases with increasing $x$ is no guarantee that $\int _0 ^\infty f(x) dx$ exists. I don't think such a theorem exists. But here if the $N-integrate$ converges it seems to be integrable for at least the values of $q$ that you are testing but its likely that the two things are unrelated. I have never used the manipulate command - let me see if I can learn about it from documentation. [...or can you write a brief explanation of what those {q,0,5,1,Appearance -> Labvelled} mean? :D...]

Comment: Of course, what I did is no proof that your integral exists, nor that _Mathematica_ can solve it. I was just trying to give you some ideas about how you could use _Mathematica_ to get more insight in your problem.